# How can we use fetch in next.js from the backed side even on those node versions were fetch is not natively available

Tags: node.js, next.js, fetch, backend

One of the notable features of next.js is that it's not just a frontend framework, it's a full-stack framework. Also things like getstaticProps, and getServersideProps (not anymore with next13) we are able to run code on the node side. Now there we can fetch the data in the backend and construct the HTML page according to the data,

Now `fetch` is available in node from version `17.5`. But before that as well we could use fetch in the next.js backend. How is that possible?

Comment: you can install it manually, [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Comment: I know that, but is next.js internally using the node-fetch library?